# AutoCompleteTextView click listener not working

Tags: android, textview, click, autocompletetextview

My autoCompleteTextView's click listener isn't working but I don't why.

```
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.userstatuslayout, R.id.listusername, values);

    editText.setThreshold(1);
    editText.setDropDownAnchor(R.id.districtsearch);
    editText.setAdapter(adapter);


    editText.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            String selection=(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Toasty.info(getApplicationContext(),selection).show();
```

Comment: please share your all related codes

Comment: Debug `String selection=(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);` in this line

Comment: try changin edittext to textview,there is no outocomplete editText

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        R.layout.userstatuslayout, R.id.listusername, values);
             AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                     findViewById(R.id...);
             textView.setAdapter(adapter);
         }
     }
```

And your ItemClickListener should be:

```
   @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Toast.makeText(AutoCompleteActivity.this,
        "Clicked item from auto completion list "
                            + adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i)
                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```